# Error "can't access property "div", animated is undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, css-animations, react-spring

I was following a tutorial trying to learn JS by cloning a dating site using component react-tinder-card as per the tutorial. While implementing, I received this error:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
can't access property "div", animated is undefined
./node_modules/react-tinder-card/index.js@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41385:21
options.factory@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49717:31
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49162:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49374:21
./src/pages/Dashboard.js@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:475:94
options.factory@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49717:31
```

Adding just the import statement `import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card'` to my code causes a runtime error. This is a snippet from react-tinder-card.

```
const React = require('react')
const { useSpring, animated } = require('@react-spring/web')

//...

// must be created outside of the TinderCard forwardRef
const AnimatedDiv = animated.div
```

My dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-spring/native": "^9.7.3",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.6.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

I've tried installing dependencies needed in the react-tinder-card dependencies but cannot get it working. Why is animated undefined in this context? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've the same issue

Comment: As posted you `"dependencies": {` is malformed.  Hard to tell if that is just a question typo or your real issue here.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following commands for installation:**

```
npm install --save react-tinder-card
npm install --save @react-spring/web@9.5.5
```

It worked for me.
I got it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tinder-card

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `react-tinder-card` version 1.5.4

> `npm i react-tinder-card@1.5.4`